# How does the "new Function" calculate a string of numeric signs and produce the result? How does this type of function declaration work in general?

Tags: javascript, new-operator

```js
let calc = '41+9-(30/2)*2';
let getResult = new Function(`return ${calc}`);
let omg = getResult();

console.log(omg); //20
```

I really don't understand how it works. Yes, I know that with such a declaration, a function has access only to global variables. As I understand, such a function **can turn any string into code**. So is it something like "**eval**"? What is the mechanism of calculating a string and converting it to the result of number type?

If anyone helped me figure this out, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, it's precisely like `eval`, just not in the local scope.

Comment: Turning strings into code is easier for an interpreted language like JavaScript than it would be for a compiled language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works because we are in the global context already:

```js
const x = 'foo'
const f = new Function(`return x`)
const result = f()
console.log(result) // 'foo'
```

The following code does not work because we are not in  the global context:

```js
(function () {
    const x = 'foo'
    const f = new Function(`return x`)
    const result = f()
    console.log(result) // ReferenceError: x is not defined
}())
```

However, your code is categorically different. String `x` is substituted into a template literal... *and then* the completed string is supplied to the `Function` constructor. So the function body is not closing over `x`. The function body is literally `return 41+9-(30/2)*2`, which is evaluated and the result is returned.

So your code will work, regardless of context:

```js
(function() {
    const x = '41+9-(30/2)*2'
    const f = new Function(`return ${x}`)
    const result = f()
    console.log(result) //20
}())
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot to figure it out!